# Simple Trig Integration. Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \dfrac{\cos x+\sin 2x}{\sin x}dx=\int \dfrac{\cos x+2\cos x\sin x}{\sin x}dx=\int \dfrac{\cos x\left(1+2\sin x\right)}{\sin x}dx$$
Substitute $u=\sin x$ and $du=\cos x\ dx$:
$$\ldots=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{u}+\dfrac{2u}{u}\right)du=\ln|\sin x|+2x+\mathcal C$$
However, the actual answer is $\ln|\sin x|+2\sin x+\mathcal C$. 
What is wrong in my integration that led me to leave out a $\sin x$?

Thank you.

Comment: $\ln(u)+2u+C$. Now $u=\sin(x)...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the evaluation of

$$
\int\left[\dfrac1u+2\dfrac uu\right]\mathrm du=\int\dfrac1u\,\mathrm du+\int2\,\mathrm du.
$$

You should get $\ln|u|+2\color{green}u+\mathcal C$ and not $\ln|u|+2\color{#C00}x+\mathcal C$, since you're integrating with respect to $\color{green}u$. Hence it should come up as $\ln|\sin x|+2\sin x+\mathcal C$.

Comment: 2(u/u) = 2? 
So wouldn't the integration of 2 be 2x?

Comment: @Joe But you're integrating with respect to $u$, so $$\int 2\,\mathrm du=2\color{#C00}u+\mathcal C.$$

Comment: Ohh! I understand that we are integrating in respect to u. That makes to total sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe You're welcome! :-)